# What is the idiomatic and functional way to iterate over successive fold results?

Tags: functional-programming, rust, fold

I have a sequence (list, iterator) `a0, a1, a2, ...`, and I use a function `f` to fold. I would like to have a generator which gives me

```
a0, f(a0, a1), f(f(a0, a1), a2), ...
```

This is similar to `FoldList` in Mathematica. Is there a `fold_list` function available? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the closest abstraction is [`Iterator::scan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan).  It is a little bit more powerful, as it has an internal mutable state (i.e. can yield a different value for the resulting iterator) and can abort early.

You could use it like this to build an iterator extension trait:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a625ebc21bfacb3ea0ae68729d925c09&version=stable)

```
pub trait FoldListExt: Iterator {
    fn fold_list<'a, St: 'a, F: 'a>(self, initial_state: St, f: F) -> Box<Iterator<Item = St> + 'a>
    where
        St: Clone,
        F: FnMut(St, Self::Item) -> St,
        Self: 'a;
}

impl<I: Iterator> FoldListExt for I {
    fn fold_list<'a, St: 'a, F: 'a>(
        self,
        initial_state: St,
        mut f: F,
    ) -> Box<Iterator<Item = St> + 'a>
    where
        St: Clone,
        F: FnMut(St, Self::Item) -> St,
        Self: 'a,
    {
        Box::new(self.scan(Some(initial_state), move |state, item| {
            let old_state = state.take().unwrap();
            *state = Some(f(old_state.clone(), item));
            Some(old_state)
        }))
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    println!(
        "{:?}",
        (0..16)
            .into_iter()
            .fold_list(0, |a, b| a + b)
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    );
}
```

I used `Option<St>` for the inner mutable state to avoid another `clone()` call.

You could use this instead:

```
Box::new(self.scan(initial_state, move |state, item| {
    let old_state = state.clone();
    *state = f(old_state.clone(), item);
    Some(old_state)
}))
```